# Pagination not working for viewsets in django rest_framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-pagination, django-2.x

**paginate.py**

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 3
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 5
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class AreaUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'areas')
```

**Views.py**

```
class AreaUsers(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AreaUsersSerializer        
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination  # Not working


    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()[:10]
        serializer = AreaUsersSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

*I just wanted to know whats wronfg with this code why the pagination is not applying.It shows all the 10 values in the api view*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):

        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'current_page': int(self.request.query_params.get('page', 1)),
            'total': self.page.paginator.count,
            'per_page': self.page_size,
            'total_pages': round(self.page.paginator.count/self.page_size, 1),
            'data': data,
        })

    class AreaUsers(viewsets.ViewSet):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AreaUsersSerializer    


        def list(self, request):
            queryset = User.objects.all()[:10]
            paginator = StandardResultsSetPagination()
            page_size = 5
            paginator.page_size = page_size
            result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
            serializer = UserSerializer(result_page, many=True)
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```